# problem driver rtl8812au ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have *USB WiFi TP-Link Archer t1u v1* and when I try to install drivers `rtl8812au` (because official drivers does not work on kernel > 3.16), it does not work even if i'm able to build and install.

I followed any type of guide but anything helps me.
I post some information abount my system:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2357:0105  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 062a:5918 Creative Labs 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The `Device 003` is my usb wifi.

```
4.18.3-041803-generic
Ubuntu 18.10
```

Comment: Why install rtl8812au when you have a mt7610u?

Comment: i did not understand mt7610u was for my wifi card, thanks a lot, it solved my problem.